# Capture only the updated value

Tags: etl

We are getting only the updated record using Time based Filter option in Integration Center?

How to get only the updated field value from "HCM SAP SuccessFactor" using ETL tool "Integration center"?

Answer (score 0):

You must use the last modified date if you want to have records on a specific date. And you can even further filter them via events and events reasons.